# How can I splice a tuple and assign to the same tuple?

Tags: python, tuples

Got some example code:

```
var = [("f1","f2","f3"),("b1","b2","b3")]

print var

var[0][0] = var[0][0][1 : len(var[0][0])]

print var
```

if i wanted to replace "f1" with "1", how would i do that? thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot, tuples are immutables. You need to create a new tuple and then you need to replace the old tuple with the new tuple.

Comment: If this had been an array instead of a tuple, this would have worked, but you should leave out the len() piece.  If there is nothing after the colon that means to go to the end `var[0][0][1:]`

Answer (score 4):

You would have to assign the whole first element of the list a new tuple since tuples are immutable.

You would do that as follows:

```
var[0] = (var[0][0][1:],)+var[0][1:]
```

After this, the value of var will be:

```
[("1","f2","f3"),("b1","b2","b3")]
```

Comment: @BraedonBetzner, Sure no problem. It's a good idea to get to know which data types are immutable and which are mutable